# Survey or good reference of taut foliations

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds, foliations, surgery-theory

I am interested in the topology of foliations.
In particular, I want to understand taut foliations, or projectively Anosov flows, and Anosov flows.
I guess that

- A. Candel and L. Conlon, Foliations I (AMS, GSM volume 23)
- A. Candel and L. Conlon, Foliations II (AMS, GSM volume 60)
- D. Calegari, Foliations and the Geometry of 3-Manifolds

are good textbooks. Are there any other good references, such as a nicely organized survey, book, or paper about these topics? I hope that these references are related to the three-dimensional manifold topology and dynamics and so on.

Comment: "projective Anosov flows" - do you mean "pseudo-Anosov flows"?  Also, are you aware of Calegari's book "Foliations and the geometry of 3-manifolds"? (As opposed to the lecture notes.)

Comment: Sergio Fenley has a survey on pseudo-Anosov flows https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2509702

Comment: I think there exist projectively anosov flow, pseudo anosov flow.

Comment: Thank you! I think It's good reference